# ordering items in doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have been looking at nestedSet behaviour in symfony using doctrine, to display a nestedSet hierachy in an admin module for my CMS.

I have come across: http://redotheoffice.com/?tag=doctrine-drag-drop-admin-generator-symfony-nestedset which at first glance looked great and I have now implemented this.

My problem comes with trying to order root nodes, since they are organised by root_id, which this implementation does not do.

I have found the following: http://blog.rajatpandit.com/2010/03/27/ordering-list-of-items-doctrine-symfony-1-4/ but I have already created a custom template to render the drag/drop nestedSet, so I'm trying to use this.

```
//generator.yml
        object_actions:
      new:
      _edit:    ~
      _delete:  ~
      moveUp:
      moveDown:
```

I've copied over the code into my `actions.class.php` and my model classes form the link above.

When trying to move a node `up` or `down` it throws an error on: `$this->current_report->getId(),` in executeUp() and executeDown()

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object`

If I then try to create the `current_report` object using `$this->current_report = new Tree()`, i then get another error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function setPosition() on a non-object` this is in my `Tree.class.php` file and the method is `swapWith()`

Position is the field I'm using to sort by rather than root_id.

If someone could help me with this, I'd muchly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-order root nodes using Doctrine Nested Sets.

If you need to do this, you can do the same thing that I did and create a fake root node level.  The idea is that level 0 will be your "fake root" node level, and your "real root" nodes start at level 1.

In this manner, you are able to re-order the fake root nodes, and it is not noticeable by a user if done correctly.

My implementation of this technique is demonstrated here:  http://cart.samedraw.com/cartadmin/categoryIndex

Source code available at github:  https://github.com/jongallant/sfCartPlugin

Comment: I simply wanted to order them by a position, since I currently have 3 root nodes and are positioned in the nested set on the frontend by their `id`. So I'd like to be able to display them in a different order, rather than deleting the nodes and re-adding them in another order. If that make sense?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this, is to have your own mechanism for keeping track of the ordering of the root nodes.  If relying on Doctrine Nested Sets only, then you are right, you can only delete/re-create the root nodes to re-order them.  This is why I am explaining that you need to create a fake root level, and store your root nodes in the first level instead.

Comment: Ok, so I've had a look at your plugin. Seems to do what I'm looking for. Might need to hack around it a little bit, as currently on the frontend as having that 'fake node' messes up my navigation menu

Comment: Yeah, you need to ensure that all of your code takes that level 0 node into account.  Not being able to re-order root nodes is quite an annoying limitation to nested sets.

Comment: It seems to create 'Categories' root node and then all other seem to be children of that. So prob gonna have to change my navigation to take that into account

Comment: Had to add: `->andWhere('g.level >= 1 ')` in the `getMenuTree` method to ignore the `fake root` you mentioned before. All works ok now.

Comment: Great.  Sorry about the confusion, but I'm sure it makes sense now.